# Differentiability and gradient of a function of a single variable

Tags: vector-analysis, differential

Suppose that $ f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+..........+a_nx_n^2,$ where $ x=(x_!,x_2,....,x_n)$ and at least one $a_j$ is not zero. Then we can conclude that

1. f is not everywhere differentiable
2. the gradient $(\nabla f)(x)\ne 0$ for every $ x \in \mathbb R^n$
3. if $ x \in \mathbb R^n$ is such that $(\nabla f)(x)=0 $ then $f(x)=0$
4. if $ x \in \mathbb R^n$ is such that $f(x)=0$ then  $(\nabla f)(x)=0 $

My attempt: $1.\;\; f'(x)=2a_1x_1+2a_2x_2+.......+2a_nx_n \Rightarrow$ f is differentiable. hence 1. is false

2. Let $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ then $(\nabla f)(x)=2x_1+2x_2$. when $x=(1,-1)$, $(\nabla f)(x)=0$. hence 2. is false
3. from (2) we have $(\nabla f)(x)=0$ but $f(x)=(1)^2+(-1)^2 \ne 0$. hence $(\nabla f)(x)=0$ does not imply that $f(x)=0$
4. Let $f(x)=x_1^2-x_2^2$ then $(\nabla f)(x)=2x_1-2x_2$. when $x=(1,-1), f(x)=0 $but $(\nabla f)(x) \ne 0$. hence  $f(x)=0$ does not imply that $(\nabla f)(x)=0$

Is my explaination correct? In the key answer it is given that option 3 is true. I am not understanding how the option 3 is correct. please help me to understand this concept

Comment: You have a concept wrong. $\nabla f \neq f'$. In your case, $\nabla f=(2a_1x_1,...,2a_nx_n)$ is a $\bf{vector}$

Comment: ok I will edit that

Comment: @Martin vacas Vignolo- if I change $ \nabla f=2a_1x_1 \hat i +2a_2x_2 \hat j +... $ then how to check whether $\nabla f =0$ or not?

Comment: here $0$ is the vector zero. i.e. each coordinate is $0$

Comment: I understood. My concept was wrong. Thank you. If $\nabla f=(0,0,...0) \Rightarrow a_1x_1=0, a_2x_2=0.... $then obviously $f(x)=0$ hence 3 is true.

Comment: exactly. For all $i$ such that $a_i\neq 0$, then $x_i=0$ and $f(x)=0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71400/discussion-between-martin-vacas-vignolo-and-priyanka).